# Can External JS be executed on a loaded page (when complete) in iOS WkWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

Can an external JS be injected into the Web View inside an iOS app (wkwebview to be specific), then executed?

Not adblock api for safari - but imagine simple JS/JQ  that does the same. Find a class, changes the class.

Can this be done? If so - are there limitations to what types of Javascript can be executed in the WkWebview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WKWebView, you have the following instance methods to execute Javascript. The JS to be execute has to be sent as a NSString to the methods.

**Obj-C**

`- (void)evaluateJavaScript:(NSString *)javaScriptString
         completionHandler:(void (^)(id,
                                     NSError *error))completionHandler`

**Swift**

`func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String,
      completionHandler completionHandler: ((AnyObject?,
                                 NSError?) -> Void)?)`

**Reference:** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:

Answer (score 2):

If you have a local JavaScript file that you want to load in and use. Similar to  adding a

`<script src="file.js" />`

you can use this in swift

```
let root = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL!
let JSURL = root.URLByAppendingPathComponent("file.js")
let JSString = try! String(contentsOfURL: JSURL)
let WKJS = WKUserScript(source: JSString, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentStart, forMainFameOnly: false)
webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(WKJS)
```